# tryin to install laravel clockwork but i have an error which is Install of itsgoingd/clockwork failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, clockwork

In **laravel 8** I am trying to install laravel clockwork where i have **php version 8.0.3** When I run

```
composer require itsgoingd/clockwork
```

command i got this error

> Installing itsgoingd/clockwork (v5.0.8): Extracting archive Install of
> itsgoingd/clockwork failed
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.
>
> [UnexpectedValueException]
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test/vendor/composer/tmp-454cb94cbea8cdcf70c06a4e0164fbba'
> is not a zip archive.
>
> require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist]
> [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install]
> [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies]
> [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies]
> [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ]
> [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest]
> [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
> [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader]
> [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] []...

Comment: Remove vendor folder and try again

Comment: also try clearing composer cache

Answer (score 0):

Delete The file `Composer.lock`, Then run this command line:

```
composer require itsgoingd/clockwork
```